# Reveal modal not opening in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation 5 in my Rails app. The reveal model works fine in chrome, firefox, IE +9. I need the same functionality of reveal model in IE 8 also. But it is not opening the popup. I have following code for opening a reveal model

```
 <a data-remote data-reveal-ajax='true' data-reveal-id='myModal' href='#{photo_url}' id='photo_30'>
    <img src='#{photo_src}' />
 </a>
```

I didnt get any errors on console when running in IE8. How can i work this in IE 8 browser?

Comment: I think Foundation 5 does not support IE8. At least not out of the box.

Comment: Yes. I knew that. I made my app except this part to work in IE8. If this also works it will be nice.